# Primes and the function $\displaystyle\prod_{\substack{p \in \mathbb{P}}} \Big( {\normalsize 1-\left(\frac{z-1}{p-1}\right)^2}\Big)$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I wrote 3 articles about prime numbers construction, and i found a relation between gaps of $d$ consecutif primes and those functions $F(z) = \displaystyle\prod_{\substack{p \in \mathbb{P}}} \Big( {\normalsize 1-\frac{z^2}{p^2}} \Big)$ and $C(z) = \displaystyle\prod_{\substack{p \in \mathbb{P}}} \Big( {\normalsize 1-\left(\frac{z-1}{p-1}\right)^2}\Big)$.

I like to know if those functions are studied before ..

http://lagrida.com/prime_numbers_construction.html

http://lagrida.com/Fondamentale_Conjonctures_Prime_Numbers.html

Comment: $G(z) =\sum_p x^p$ and $G_k \sum_p p^k z^p$ is the core of the proof of the weak Goldbach conjecture (coefficients of $G(z)^2$, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinogradov%27s_theorem ) and it may be used for the twin prime conjecture ($\int_0^{2\pi} G(z e^{i t})G(z e^{-i t})$ not being a polynomial). How do you look at the prime gap from it ? Then $\log \prod_p (1-\frac{z^2}{p^2}) = -\sum_{m \ge 1} \frac{G_{-2}(z^{2m})}{m}$

Comment: I study the function $\Upsilon_{b,q}(d) = \displaystyle{\small \prod_{\substack{b \leq a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} \left({\normalsize 1-\frac{d}{a}}\right)}$ for $b,q \in \mathbb{P}$ and $d \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: And i proof that :
$\Upsilon_{b,q}(d) \sim \displaystyle\left\{ \begin{array}{cl}\dfrac{C_b(2) C_b(4) \cdots C_b(d) \, e^{- d \gamma}}{F_b(0) F_b(2) F_b(4) \cdots F_b(d-2) K_b^d} \,\, \dfrac{1}{\ln^d(q)} & \text{ if } \ \text{d is even} \\ \\\dfrac{C_b(3) C_b(5) \cdots C_b(d) \, e^{- d \gamma}}{F_b(1) F_b(3) \cdots F_b(d-2) K_b^d} \,\, \dfrac{1}{\ln^d(q)} & \text{ if } \ \text{d is odd}\end{array} \right.$

Comment: And $K_b = \displaystyle{\small \prod_{\substack{a < b \\ \text{a prime}}} \left({\normalsize 1-\frac{1}{a}}\right)}$.
Show that if we denote $q(n)$ the small prime verify $n < \displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a \leq q(n) \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a} \right)}$ and $I_n$ the number of elements less than $n$ and coprime to $\displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a \leq q(n) \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a} \right)}$ Then $I_n \sim \displaystyle e^{-\gamma} \frac{n}{\ln\ln(n)}$

Comment: $F_b(z) = \displaystyle{\small \prod_{\substack{b \leq a \\ \text{a prime}}} \left({\normalsize 1-\frac{z^2}{a^2}}\right)}$
$C_b(z) = \displaystyle{\small \prod_{\substack{b \leq a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} \left({\normalsize 1-\left(\frac{z-1}{a-1}\right)^2}\right)}$

Consider the set $\displaystyle \mathcal{B}_q=\{b \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \, | \, b \wedge {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a} \right)}=1 \text{ and } b \leq {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a} \right)} \}$

Comment: And that is related to twin prime conjecture or triplet conjecture (quadriple conjecture ...) : http://lagrida.com/Fondamentale_Conjonctures_Prime_Numbers.html